# Python3, with pandas.dataframe, how to select certain data by some rules to show

Tags: python-3.x, select, dataframe, rule

I have a pandas.dataframe, and I want to select certain data by some rules.

The following codes generate the dataframe

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

today = datetime.date.today()
dates = list()
for k in range(10):
    a_day = today - datetime.timedelta(days=k)
    dates.append(np.datetime64(a_day))

np.random.seed(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(10, 3)),
                  columns=('other1', 'actual', 'other2'),
                  index=['{}'.format(i) for i in range(10)])

df.insert(0, 'dates', dates)
df['err_m'] = np.random.rand(10, 1)*0.1
df['std'] = np.random.rand(10, 1)*0.05
df['gain'] = np.random.rand(10, 1)
```

Now, I want select by the following rules:

```
1. compute the sum of 'err_m' and 'std', then sort the df so that the sum is descending
2. from the result of step 1, select the part where 'actual' is > 50
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new column and then sort by this one:

   ```
   df['errsum'] = df['err_m'] + df['std']
   # Return a sorted dataframe
   df_sorted = df.sort('errsum', ascending = False)
   ```
2. Select the lines you want

   ```
    # Create an array with True where the condition is met
    selector = df_sorted['errsum'] > 50
    # Return a view of sorted_dataframe with only the lines you want
    df_sorted[selector]
   ```